# Did anyone ever use comedy as a combat tactic?

Tags: warfare, combat

Fighters are known to use war-cries, taunts, gestures and postures before engaging their enemy in order to increase their own adrenaline or to intimidate the enemy or throw off their concentration.

A Chinese emperor once conscripted criminal prisoners to approach the enemy and then commit suicide in order to mortify the enemy.

**Is there any historic account of trying to make the enemy laugh as a diversion tactic?**

Comment: ["What the hell are we supposed to use, man, harsh language?"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i33DX9Wjd7E)

Comment: [There is an example in this documentary](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ienp4J3pW7U)

Comment: Dying is easier than comedy.

Answer (score 2):

Technically, yes, if you consider the assassination of Abraham Lincoln by John Wilkes Booth:

(Emphasis added)

> **Although he had never starred in the play himself, Booth knew the play
>   by heart, and thus waited for the precise moment when actor Harry Hawk**
>   (playing the lead role of the "cousin", Asa Trenchard), **would be on
>   stage alone to speak what was considered the funniest line of the
>   play. Booth hoped to employ the enthusiastic response of the audience
>   to muffle the sound of his gunshot.** With the stage to himself, Asa
>   (Hawk) responded to the recently departed Mrs. Mountchessington,
>   "Don't know the manners of good society, eh? Well, I guess I know
>   enough to turn you inside out, old gal; you sockdologizing old
>   man-trap!" **Hysterical laughter began permeating the theatre. Lincoln
>   was laughing at this line when he was shot**

[From the Assassination of Abraham Lincoln Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assassination_of_Abraham_Lincoln#cite_note-30).

Comment: Assassination is not a combat tactic.

Comment: His last statement for the question was "Is there any historic account of trying to make the enemy laugh as a diversion tactic?" Waiting until an audience was in the thrall of intense laugher in order to murder a president certainly fits the requirement of the phrase "diversion tactic."